# accessing a python int literals methods

Tags: python, object, syntax, integer, literals

Since everything is an object in python, even literals, we are typically allowed to call methods directly on a literal.

ex:

```
'hello'.upper()
```

In theory, it seems like the same thing should be allowed for int literals

ex:

```
4.bit_length()
```

However, this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas? Thanks!