# Why does 1.__add__(2) not work out?

Tags: python, operator-keyword, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [accessing a python int literals methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955703/accessing-a-python-int-literals-methods)

In Python, `everything is an object`.

But then again, why doesn't the following snippet work?

```
1.__add__(2)
```

However, this does work:

```
n = 1
n.__add__(2)
```

What is the difference between `n` and `1`?

Isn't it a design failure that it doesn't work?
For instance, it does work with `string` literals as well.

```
"one".__add__("two")
```

For comparison, it works well on other purely object oriented languages too.

Let's take a closer look at this compiling c# example:

```
Console.WriteLine(100.ToString());
```

Then again, what distinguishes `Python` from `C#` in the perspective of `everything is an object`?

Comment: It is an object you just need brackets around it `(1).__add__(2)`

Comment: @jamylak Please explain why the brackets are required.

Comment: @Michael because lexer gets confused thinking it's a floating point literal.

Comment: Why can't the lexer recognize that after the period there is a [a-z][A-Z] and therefore interpret it as an object. I mean, that is actually a good point why variable/method names cannot start with a number!

Comment: Michael: Try typing `1.e8` and observing what it prints, comparing it to what you think it should print. Now try `1.e+8` and `1.e-8`. I think it would be reasonable if *you* were confused by now, so I wouldn't really blame the lexer. :P

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Python's parser is deliberately very simple - one of the constraints it enforces on itself is that, to figure out what a token means, it can only look one token to the right (it is an [LL(1) parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)).

So, it sees [number][dot], and determines that it is a floating point literal. `'_'` isn't a valid character to have in a floating point literal, so it gives a syntax error.

The most obvious and most common way to overcome this is to put the number in parentheses:

```
(1).__add__(2)
```

This forces it to interpret the `1` as an integer literal, and the dot as attribute access, within the limitations of the parser.

Another interesting workaround is this:

```
>>> 1 .__add__(2) 
3
```

That is, add a space before the `.`. It turns out that Python always allows a space there for any attribute lookup:

```
>>> range(4) .count(3)
1
```

I found this quite surprising, but it seems that Python treats `.` under similar rules to `+`, and so will allow as much space as you like around it.

Comment: Thanks for the parser insight, mentioning LL(1)!

Comment: @lvc The extra space there is not a special case, the python lexer allows any amount of white space between most things. eg. `range    ( 4  )   .  count  (  3  )` also works (SO won't let me put more than one space here but it works for more)

Comment: @jamylak I see. I've reedited my answer with that in mind.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is the lexer that needs to decide whether the "." is part of a floating-point literal or a delimiter token.

Answer (score 10):

Python interprets `1.` as float so you have to add parens:

```
>>> (1).__add__(2)
3
```

or space:

```
>>> 1 .__add__(2)
3
```

If you want float value here just put 2 dots.

```
>>> 1..__add__(2) #float
3.0
```

Comment: OK, I admit the 1..__add__ surprised me. I guess this is an argument against adding range literals (like Ruby), as it would complicate the parser.