# Why can't I call methods directly on int objects?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [accessing a python int literals methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955703/accessing-a-python-int-literals-methods)
>   [Integer literal is an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802214/integer-literal-is-an-object-in-python)

In python it's possible, and sometimes even common, to call methods or look up attributes directly on literals:

```
>>> "-".join("abc")
'a-b-c'
>>> {1: 3, 2: 9}.pop(1)
3
>>> 3j.imag
3.0
>>> 8.0.__add__(8)
16.0
```

But for some reason this does not work on integer objects:

```
>>> 3.__add__(42)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3.__add__(42)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why not?

Comment: @Martijn I could not find any duplicate. If someone can point to one I'll delete this question.

Comment: There you go, I knew it was here already. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- apparently twice :)

Comment: @mgilson: there are more still, this comes up every once in a while.

Comment: Hmm, can't delete since I've answered it. Should I flag it then?

Comment: @lazyr: already flagged.

Comment: And of course: [Why does 1.__add__(2) not work out?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12025531)

Answer (score 9):

As is normally the case when I start typing a Stack Overflow question, I find the likely answer myself as I'm researching it. Well, today I'm posting the question anyway, along with what I think is the answer:

It does not work for integers because the `.` is interpreted as a decimal point by the parser. The float example works because the parser knows that the second period must be attribute lookup -- there is no ambiguity in this case.

Comment: Did you try `(3).__add__(42)`? (No Python on this box for a quick try)

Comment: @dario_ramos Yes, and it works, so this supports my theory.